# When I try to Update dbo.Customer, it keeps on telling me that isProblemAccount is invalid on Line 4, 6 and 9

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CUSTOMER
ADD isProblemAccount Bit NULL DEFAULT '0';

UPDATE dbo.CUSTOMER
SET isProblemAccount = 0;

UPDATE dbo.CUSTOMER
SET isProblemAccount = 1
    WHERE LastName = 'Gliddens'
        AND FirstName = 'Melinda';

SELECT CustomerID, LastName, FirstName, isProblemAccount
FROM dbo.CUSTOMER;
```

Comment: Which is the database? MySql, Oracle, ....

Comment: SQL server management studio

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CUSTOMER
    ADD [isProblemAccount] bit NULL DEFAULT ((0)); -- don't use '0'
GO -- do the change in separate batch

UPDATE dbo.CUSTOMER
SET isProblemAccount = 0
GO -- after every update

UPDATE dbo.CUSTOMER
SET isProblemAccount = 1
WHERE LastName = 'Doe'
AND FirstName = 'John'
GO

SELECT CustomerID, LastName, FirstName, isProblemAccount
FROM dbo.CUSTOMER
```

Also, if you're expecting a `isProblemAccount` for every record going forward, specify the column as `NOT NULL` instead, and skip the first update statement:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CUSTOMER
    ADD [isProblemAccount] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)); -- don't use '0'
GO -- do the change in separate batch

UPDATE dbo.CUSTOMER
SET isProblemAccount = 1
WHERE LastName = 'Doe'
AND FirstName = 'John'
GO

SELECT CustomerID, LastName, FirstName, isProblemAccount
FROM dbo.CUSTOMER
```

Comment: I think you only need a `GO` after the `ALTER TABLE`, and not after each `UPDATE`.

Comment: @Andrew: Could be, just thought I'd cover all the bases.